# make links with javascript/jquery from html class

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my site have 3 box, how create with js a link from a html class

example my box is this:

```
<div class="box1">content</div>
<div class="box2">content</div>
<div class="box3">content</div>
```

how create a link for class box1,box2,box3

Comment: what do you mean _how create a link for class box1,box2,box3_??

Comment: yes, but with javascript/jquery

Comment: why use javascript to create a link when you can just give a link in your DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous. if this is what you want:

```
    <div id = "box1" class="box1">content</div>

    <script>
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("box1");
    $( ".box1" ).replaceWith( "<a href="www.google.com" class="box1">content</a>" );
    </script>
```

Comment: without id , have solution ?

Comment: i edited the answer to fetch all elements that use the class box1, can be one or many.
an Id is used for unique identifaction of the DOM element but  a class is associated with many elements.

Comment: not understand your script, i request a simple link for box1 when the mouse go on hover, example box1 link : http://google.it ecc, only with class

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you are trying to do, turning the class into a link. http://jsfiddle.net/xthne2bm/1/

HTML

```
<div class="box1">content</div>
<div class="box2">content</div>
<div class="box3">content</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('[class^="box"').each(function () {
    var link = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).wrapInner('<a>').find('a').attr('href', link);
});
```